# Issue On Scrolling to A Row in Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this <kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/S64w7/)**</kbd> and let me know how I can use jquery to scroll to the selected row or animate that row to the middle of the scrolled div `sc`?

Here is the code:

```
<div id="sc">
    <table id="mytable"></table>
</div>
<button class="25">Scrool to 25</button>
<button class="75">Scrool to 75</button>
<button class="125">Scrool to 125</button>
<button class="199">Scrool to 199</button>
<button class="0">Scrool to 0</button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
     $('#mytable').append('<tr class=' + i + '><td>This is Row' + i + ' </td></tr>');
     $("#125").click(function() {
     $('#sc').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#sc").offset().top}, 2000);
 });
      }
});
<script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Comment: Hi estshy I already tried this     $("#125").click(function() {
    $('#sc').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#sc").offset().top
    }, 2000);
}); but nothing happend!

Comment: You may use instead plugin animatescroll (http://plugins.compzets.com/animatescroll/). It's simple and give better effect.

Answer (score 1):

You may also used named anchors `<a name="row10">...</a>` and in your anchor tag just refer to the `#tag` like:

```
<a href="#row10">...</a>
```

Simplistic approach, should work for you unless you want some fancy animation and other stuff.